# How to change json schema based on a property existence?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

My goal is to change the schema based on a property existence.
These are my schemas:

```
sample = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "description": {"type": "string", "minLength": 1, "pattern": "^.*\w+.*$"},
        "owner_id": {"type": "string"},
        "privacy_setting": {"type": "string", "enum": ["private","group","account","public"]},
        "iam": iam,
        "timestamp": {"type": "integer", "minimum": 1000000000000, "maximum": 9999999999999},
        "protocols": {"type": "array", "items": protocol},
        "measurements": {"type": "array", "items": measurement}
    },
    "required": ["description","owner_id"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}

existing_sample = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "string"},
        "protocols": {"type": "array", "items": protocol},
        "measurements": {"type": "array", "items": measurement}
    },
    "required": ["id"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}

# final schema
final = {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^.+$": {
            "if": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {"type": "string"}
                }
            },
            "then": existing_sample,
            "else": sample
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": False
}
```

The idea is to follow the "existing_sample" schema in case "id" property exists and follow the "sample" schema in case it's missing.

It works as expected when "id" exists, which means that if an unspecified property appears it will raise the exception:

> Additional properties are not allowed

but in case the "id" property is missing it will return the exception:

> 'id' is a required property

as if it still follows the "existing_sample" schema.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide your instance data that you expect to pass and fail, and say which doesn't do as you expect? Currently I cannot tell what is currently happening and what you want to happen from your question.

Comment: @Relequestual thanks for the reply!..figured it out eventually

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my condition wasn't right. I needed to **require** an "id" property instead of just specifying the "id" property schema.
The following works as expected:

```py
# existing sample schema
existing_sample = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {"type": "string"},
        "protocols": {"type": "array", "items": protocol},
        "measurements": {"type": "array", "items": measurement}
    },
    "required": ["id"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}


# sample schema
sample = {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "owner_id": {"type": "string"},
        "description": {"type": "string", "minLength": 1, "pattern": "^.*\w+.*$"},
        "privacy_setting": {"type": "string", "enum": ["private","group","account","public"]},
        "iam": iam,
        "timestamp": {"type": "integer", "minimum": 1000000000000, "maximum": 9999999999999},
        "protocols": {"type": "array", "items": protocol},
        "measurements": {"type": "array", "items": measurement}
    },
    "required": ["description","owner_id"],
    "additionalProperties": False
}

# condition to choose between existing sample schema to new sample schema
# based on "id" property appearance
condition = {
    "type": "object",
    "if": {
        "required": ["id"],
    },
    "then": existing_sample,
    "else": sample
}

# final schema
final = {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
        "^.+$": condition
    }
}
```